# Unable to transfer app

Tags: android, google-play

In Android ecosystem, you can transfer an app from a developer to another through an option in Developer Console. There is a simple form whose fields are:

- First name
- Last name
- Developer name for your target account
- Original account email address
- Account currently linked to the app(s)
- Transaction ID for the original account’s Developer Console registration
- Target account email address
- Account where you’d like to transfer the app(s)
- Transaction ID for the target account’s Developer Console registration
- App and package names you want to transfer.

After I fill all of those, the page returns an error about **Transaction ID for the target** that underlines that field in red and says "Please enter the Google Wallet Transaction ID for Developer Account registration"

I've double/triple checked the target transaction ID and it should be correct. What could be the problem? I believe that the form validation may be returning some kind of non specific error.

Has anybody had this issue before?

Comment: `In Android, you can transfer an app from a developer to another through an option in Developer Console. `. I have never seen such a console in Android. How does one open it?

Comment: See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appt

Comment: I do not consider that a console 'in Android'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was caused by a lacking documentation describing the process. The transaction ID can't be copy+pasted as is, but you need to transform it. They (google) provide you that id, so you would think that that's all you need. It was not the case. We had to remove some numbers at the start and replace them with '0'

For example, you have to replace all the digits before the first dot with ONE zero.

> **123456789**.G.123456798 --> **0**.G.123456789

After that, all worked like expected.

Comment: This doesn't help us. You should describe the process that you have made. How you removed these 0's?

Comment: You have to replace all the digits before the first dot with ONE zero. For example: 123456789.G.123456798 -> 0.G.123456789

Comment: I follow this link and worked for me https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?visit_id=1-636572578783628427-2639181401&rd=1